# Deleting Files - Skip Files in Use

Tags: c#, file, directory

I'm trying to delete the files in a directory, but I get errors when attempting to remove the files which are currently in use. Is there a way to skip the files that are currently in use and delete the rest of them? Thanks.

```
foreach(var file in Directory.GetFiles(tempPath))
{
    File.Delete(file);
}
```

That's the code I have so far, not sure how to go about this.

Comment: I mean, the code won't delete the files that are in use, so it really doesn't even matter. If you don't want errors to show, you could try to catch the exception thrown when it tries deleting files in usage, but it really doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easier way is surrounding your code with a [`try-catch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch) block. Something like this:

```
foreach(var file in Directory.GetFiles(tempPath))
{
    try 
    {
        File.Delete(file);
    } 
    catch (Exception) 
    {
        //Decide what you want to do here, you can either 
        //ask user to retry if the file is in use
        //Or ignore the failure and continue, or...
    }          
}
```

Comment: It seems like I was over complicating it in my head, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

you can check by try catch

```
private bool IsLocked(string filePath)
    {

        FileInfo f = new FileInfo(filePath);
        FileStream stream = null;

        try
        {
            stream = f.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None);
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            return true;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (stream != null)
                stream.Close();
        }
        return false;
    }


    public void RemoveFile(string folderPath)
    {
        foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(folderPath))
        {
            if (!IsLocked(file))
            {
                File.Delete(file);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap File.Delete in a try { } catch block