# skipping files while deleting that are currently in use

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

i try to make a temp cleaner and the program it self works but how can i write the programm that it skips the files that are currently in use?

here is the script i used

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);

    foreach (FileInfo file in di.GetFiles())
    {
        file.Delete(); 
    }
    foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in di.GetDirectories())
    {
        dir.Delete(true); 
    }
```

Comment: You could throw a try catch around it, and do nothing in the catch

Comment: @Kevin Or you'd react according to the exception thrown?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876473/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-file-is-in-use

Comment: @Kevin how do i do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deleting Files - Skip Files in Use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53361930/deleting-files-skip-files-in-use)